# Looping a (working) batch file over a list

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this beautiful batch file I've got working with lots of help from the internet.  What it does is look at my source directory, and copy all of the *.pst files it finds there into a dest directory.  It preserves the folder structure, but changes the extension from pst to myMail.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set SOURCE_DIR=c:\PST\Exchange Folder\
set DEST_DIR=U:\testPST\
set FILENAMES_TO_COPY=*.pst

for /R "%SOURCE_DIR%" %%F IN (%FILENAMES_TO_COPY%) do (
    if exist "%%F" (
        set d=%%~dpa
        set FILE_DIR=%%~dpF
        set FILE_INTERMEDIATE_DIR=!FILE_DIR:%SOURCE_DIR%=!
        if not exist "%DEST_DIR%!FILE_INTERMEDIATE_DIR!" (
            mkdir "%DEST_DIR%!FILE_INTERMEDIATE_DIR!"
        )
        COPY /y "%%F" "%DEST_DIR%!FILE_INTERMEDIATE_DIR!%%~nF.myMail"
    )
)
```

This works perfectly, but I want to add a way to easily add new source folders.  For example, what if I have 4 likely places that hold pst files that I want the script to work on?  I've looked into lists, but I think the spaces in my directory paths are giving me problems.

I was hoping that I could just do something like the following, where I add a list at the top, and essentially paste most of my existing code into an additional loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set DEST_DIR=U:\testPST\
set FILENAMES_TO_COPY=*.pst

set list="c:\PST\Exchange Folder" "c:\users\auser\documents\mail" 
(
    for %%i in (%list%) do (
        set SOURCE_DIR=%%i
        for /R "%SOURCE_DIR%" %%F IN (%FILENAMES_TO_COPY%) do (
            if exist "%%F" (
                set d=%%~dpa
                set FILE_DIR=%%~dpF
                set FILE_INTERMEDIATE_DIR=!FILE_DIR:%SOURCE_DIR%=!
                if not exist "%DEST_DIR%!FILE_INTERMEDIATE_DIR!" (
                    mkdir "%DEST_DIR%!FILE_INTERMEDIATE_DIR!"
                )
                COPY /y "%%F" "%DEST_DIR%!FILE_INTERMEDIATE_DIR!%%~nF.myMail"
            )
        )
        )
    )
)
PAUSE
```

Anyways, that's the stage I'm at - does anyone have any bright ideas?

Comment: First off - you have one too many closing brackets (before the PAUSE).

Answer (score 2):

**One** way you can handle this is to change the DEST_DIR from a string to `%1` and then create another batch file to

```
call foo.bat "c:\source_1"
call foo.bat "c:\source_2"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change

```
    for /R "%SOURCE_DIR%" %%F IN (%FILENAMES_TO_COPY%) do (
```

to

```
    for /R "%%~i" %%F IN (%FILENAMES_TO_COPY%) do (
```

AND

```
            set FILE_INTERMEDIATE_DIR=!FILE_DIR:%SOURCE_DIR%=!
```

to

```
            set FILE_INTERMEDIATE_DIR=!FILE_DIR:%%~i=!
```

Then at least in theory, your goal could be achieved.

The problem is with the use of `%var%` and `!var!`. The former means 'the value of `var` when the entire `FOR..%%i..` statement is encountered (up to its closing parenthesis) - (ie. the "parse-time" value). The second means 'the value of `var` as it changes within the loop' (ie. the "run-time" value)

`%%x` - the value of the metavariable (loop-control variable) `x` is always the run-time value. The prefied `~` means (in this case) "remove the enclosing quotes"